# How can i get rid of this error?'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

My code is below:

```
def count(lst):
    even=0
    odd=0
    for i in lst:
        if i%2==0:
            even+=1
        
        else:
            odd+=1
    return even,odd
        
lst=[11,13,16,17,19,20]
even,odd=count(lst)
print("Even : {} and Odd :{}",format[even,odd])
```

When I run,i get following error pointing to last line:
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I am trying my best to follow this tutorial but still i got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to write

```
print("Even : {} and Odd :{}".format(even,odd))
```

As the error clearly says, you try to reach an index of the built-in function (format in this case) by writing

```
format[even, odd]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
print(f"Even: {even} and Odd: {odd}")
```

You have to use a `f-string` which will help convert variables into your strings. Tip: put your variables in the curly brackets.

Or if you want to use the `.format`:

```
print("Even: {} and Odd: {}".format(even, odd))
```

The `.format` function uses [the following format](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/docs/builtins.str.format):

> `str.format()`

Your errors:

- You used square brackets (which are used for lists or indexes) instead of normal brackets
- You used `,` instead of `.` to denote the function